# Weird light instead of pick?

Tags: guitar-effects, rock-n-roll

I've been on post rock concert (God is an Astronaut if it helps) and during one song the guitarist was using something looking like tiny laptop power supply with little light (pickup side).

He was still using his left hand (fretboard side) like playing normally.

What was that? Is this a custom effect or something?

Comment: +1 for God is an Astronaut :)
And I think you're refering to an EBow so +1 to Dmitry's answer as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps it was [EBow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBow). It amplifies string vibrations (using magnetic fields) providing very controllable feedback effect which allows to get very smooth and sustained sound.

Also check out [this video on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIWMrK67_bk). Although it is old it demonstrates very wide range of possibilities of this device.

Comment: The device Phil Keaggy is using in that video is a very old model, so it's worth noting that the current model Ebows do have a little blue light on the bottom.

Comment: @NReilingh light in device I've seen was also blue so it was EBow and he used it to aim single string :)

Comment: Keaggy is a master at the eBow. Seeing him use it live is both inspiring and disgusting, because it shows what it can do, and how far I have to go to get there. They're very fun on acoustic guitars too. (I've got an original eBow in my effects case.)